# UnknownHostException: graph.facebook.com

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am trying to login with facebook, with spring-social, but after of login in facebook I got the next error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController -     Exception while completing OAuth 2 connection: 
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST     request for    "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token":graph.facebook.com; nested     exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: graph.facebook.com
```

In the rest template class, after doExecute(expanded, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor); appears the error, expanded is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token, method POST.

My code is from spring-social-samples, from github.Maybe the problem is in my account of facebook developer???

Comment: try pinging graph.facebook.com to see if you can see it, is it accessed thru a proxy?

Comment: yes, it is accessed.

Comment: No, that is not an issue with your FB account, but a network issue on your server – looks like it is not able to resolve the host name to an IP address. Ask your server admin to look into the issue.

Comment: CBroe I'm not sure with your responde, because If I write in my browser https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token, my browser will return me error: {
message: "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
type: "OAuthException",
code: 191,
fbtrace_id: "Du+NeoMBe+6"
}
}

Comment: excecute this command "nslookup graph.facebook.com" in the same machine where your application is running

Comment: try to update the dependencies to the latest version, spring-social 1.14 and spring-social-facebook 2.0.3. The samples would just not work for me until the dependencies were updated to the latest.